# index.php 301 Redirect not working for Joomla site

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I tried below code in .htaccess with my Joomla site but it is not working at all:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php /
```

I also tried:

```
Redirect 301 www.domain.com/index.php www.domain.com/
```

Basically I don't want to have duplicate pages and currently I can view the home page with index.php and without.

I have no idea why Joomla does this but it's not working at all. I've also done 301 redirect under Artio SEO component but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.yourdomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Great. It's working thank you. Do we know why above Redirect 301 did not work?